# Image drops down when menu opens

Tags: html, css, image

```
.nav-btn {
        display: block;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        /*text-align: right;*/
        /*right: 2%;*/
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-top: 20px;
        /*position: absolute;*/
    }
    .nav-btn:before {
        background-image: url('http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/mobile_menu_white.png');
        background-size: 28px 28px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-right: 15px;
        width: 28px;
        height: 28px;
        content:"";
        display: block;
        padding-top: 0;
        float: right;
    }
```

I have a menu that appears in my `640px` media query. Whenever the button is selected, for some reason the image goes down under my menu. I want the image to stay in the same spot regardless of the menu being open or closed.

Plus the `background-color` turns to blue when the button is clicked on?

What is causing this?

Comment: and, what js/jquery really do when we click on mobile menu button....

Comment: All I have is a slideToggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the float:right on .nav-btn. I am not even sure you need the float:right. When I toggle or disable the float:right, nothing changes, so it seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: You are right! Thanks. I never knew you could toggle behavior in the developer tools until now. This will help me a bunch in the future.